# Android Studio Resolve error. failed to find target android-18

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Error image]

Hello guys, Now I'm face on some error using android studio(0.3.6 version) (using at win8)

I cloned project from bitbucket and import project, but that error message occured.

what should I do?

ah! Project make from android studio version 0.3.2. is this reason?

In addition, how can I import external library at 0.3.6 project structure?
should I make new module? then what?

anyway! thanks in advance. I hope to get answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio comes bundled with its own SDK, which may not have the same Android API targets you used to create the project in Eclipse. You can either add the APIs to Android Studio's SDK  by clicking on the SDK Manager toolbar icon in Android Studio if you have a project open, or if you don't, from the Welcome screen choose Configure > SDK Manager, or you can tell Android Studio to use the same SDK you were using from Eclipse: Project Structure > Android SDK if you have a project open, or Welcome > Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure > Android SDK if you don't.

Comment: Oops! Thanks now I got it!

Comment: I'll try! and...you know other question about import library? T.T

Comment: Break that out into a different question (edit this question to remove it from here), and provide more information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: When you say "AS comes with its own SDK", that confuses me.  Coming from a Windows background, I don't understand why there isn't one single SDK provided by Google?  (In Windows, there's only the Platform SDK provided by Microsoft.)  I may be missing something fundamental in my understanding of the Google/Android world.  Would appreciate your help.  Thank you.

Comment: Also: Doesn't the latest API level encompass all the previous API levels?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Compile the project with latest version of android , go to sdk manager and install the android api level 18 and then in your project right click open android tools and add support library. clean the project and restart the eclipse.

Comment: hmm actually I use android studio not eclipse, and I can't find 'android tools' you told me. also can't know find 'project right click'